# Is there any alternative for the cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview that is currently maintained?

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, webview, crosswalk

I have a Cordova project that is using the Android System WebView (as it should by default), but the problem is:

- The Android is in a wearable device, which means its System WebView component (version 55) is not upgradable;
- My application needs a newer version of the Chromium WebView (version 77+);
- Although I cannot upgrade the System WebView component, I managed to install a newer version of it (version 80) and it's shown on the Settings' applications list.

I know that, on earlier Android versions, Crosswalk (https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview) did the trick to get rid of the System WebView, but it is not maintained anymore. The v3 (https://github.com/ardabeyazoglu/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview-v3) says, "only bug fixes", but when built, it seems to change nothing in the project, because the application still uses WebView version 55.

Does anybody know how to import a specific WebView version (i.e. 80) in Cordova, even if it's not the System's default? Or even a trick that I could do to use Crosswalk v3 the right way would help a lot!

Thanks you!

Comment: Did you determine this?

Answer (score 2):

There is this fork that is updated to chromium 77

https://github.com/Constaline/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview-v3/

you have to install it from github directly with `cordova plugin add https://github.com/Constaline/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview-v3/`

but I wasn't able to make my project build after installing the plugin